# Xcode, React Native and redux logger: [TOO BIG formatValueCalls XXX exceeded limit of 200]

Tags: xcode, react-native, redux-logger

When running React Native, without debug js remotely, Xcode shows a lot of logs saying:

```
[TOO BIG formatValueCalls XXX exceeded limit of 200]
```

The logs seem to appear in redux logger entries.

The errors are thrown by React Native, from a file called `console.js` in `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/polyfills/console.js`

Should this be preoccupying? I couldn't find anything related to this on the internet.

Answer (score 9):

OK, those messages come from the console.js module in React Native. This module pipes console.log to NSLog on iOS. I am logging out some biiiig objects (which I need to fix), and this module is clipping them (rightly so). So look for places in your code where you're doing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

check the Metro Bundler's logs, there must be a lot of big objects, but these logs are not shown in xcode, just `[TOO BIG formatValueCalls XXX exceeded limit of 200]` , I think we can just ignore this warning.

Comment: Please include where the logs are to be found. I'm afraid that I wouldn't deem: 'In the Terminal' to be specific enough. :-)

Comment: the Metro Bundler, which you will not miss it in the terminal when you run 'yarn start'

Comment: Please edit your answer and include that, to make it easily digestible for others. Especially ones with less experience than you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ……man, if someone don't know what "metro bundler" or "react native start" or"yarn start" is,  they will even don't know what is "react native" too, if then don't know it, then they will not be here, I don't know what "additional supporting information"? should I post all of react native 's official documents??!